# Не понимаю как добавить GeoObjectTapListener к картам yandex.maps

Tags: android, яндекс-карты

делаю так:

```
mapView!!.map.addTapListener(clickListener)
clickListener - GeoObjectTapListener
```

но при нажатии на объект, который добавлен на карте через

```
mapView!!.map.mapObjects.addPlacemark
```

не вызывается метод у `GeoObjectTapListener`

```
onObjectTap
```